# Splitting, Filtering and Selecting data based on date (and a bit more)

Tags: r, filtering, correlation

So first, some example data

```
day <- c("2004-02-13", "2004-02-13", "2004-12-10", "2004-12-10", "2005-05-01", "2005-05-01", "2005-11-29", "2005-11-29", "2007-06-22", "2007-06-24")
test <- c('weight', 'metabolic rate', 'weight', 'metabolic rate', 'weight', 'metabolic rate', 'weight', 'metabolic rate', 'weight', 'metabolic rate')
testvalue <- c(90, 2300, 80, 2200, 100, 2500, 70, 2000, 65, 1800)
```

```
data <- data.frame(day, test, testvalue)
```

```
data$day <- as.Date(data$day)
```

I have a dataset that is build up like the following: The real goal is make a pearsons correlation on the relationship between weight and metabolic weight, with the requirement that the test's must've been made on the same day.

```
data
```

I want the test's that have been made on the same day to get paired.
And all data that stand alone, must be discarded (as for weight "65" and metabolic rate "1800"). The following is what I wanna end up with (in this example).
I believe there might be a function to discard dates which isn't duplicates, however I still don't know how to seperate the columns.

```
weight <- c(90, 80, 100, 70)
metabolic_rate <-c(2300,2200,2500,2000)
end_result <- data.frame(weight, metabolic_rate)
end_result
```

```
cor.test(end_result$weight, end_result$metabolic_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```r
require(magrittr)
require(tidyr)

dt <- spread(data, key = 'test', value = 'testvalue') %>% na.omit
with(dt,
     cor.test(`metabolic rate`, `weight`)
)
```

Here, you cast the data by `test` versus `day`, and through `na.omit` remove those rows that have at least one `NA` value.

Comment: thanks for answering. I can't make it work with reshape2. It would seem it's retired: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.4

Comment: @RasmusFrosted wow, sad to see ``dcast`` retired. It [seems that](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidyverse-alternative-to-reshape2-dcast/12692) ``spread`` is the latest way to go

Comment: @RasmusFrosted edited with the ``tidyr`` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `tidyr`:

```
end_result <- data |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = test, values_from = testvalue) |>
  na.omit() 

cor.test(end_result$weight, end_result$"metabolic rate")
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer! When I apply this code to my real code, the list of "weight" and "metabolic rate" just erases all numbers and puts <dbl[1]> in instead OR <NULL>. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This may be because the data is not a simple vector of numbers - is it a list?  Otherwise, I can't think of a reason.  The `pivot_wider()` is not doing much except rearranging the data